# Simple constexpr - C26498 warning and C2131 error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to learn about `const` and `constexpr` and have run into the error C26498 on VS2019. However, my example is almost the same as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26498?view=vs-2019):

```
constexpr int myInt();
constexpr int getMyValue();
void foo();

int main()
{
    int val1 = myInt(); // C26498 warning (mark variable constexpr)
    const int val2 = myInt();    // C26498 warning (mark variable constexpr)
    constexpr int val3 = myInt();  // C2131 error (expression did not evaluate to a constant)
    foo();
}

constexpr int myInt() { return 1; }

constexpr int getMyValue() { return 1; }

void foo() { constexpr int val0 = getMyValue(); // no C26498 }
```

**Edit:** As requested, here is the error list (VS2019):

> Warning   C26498  - The function 'myInt' is constexpr, mark variable 'val1'
> constexpr if compile-time evaluation is desired (con.5).  line 13
>
> Warning   C26498  - The function 'myInt' is constexpr, mark variable 'val2'
> constexpr if compile-time evaluation is desired (con.5).  line 14
>
> Error C2131   - expression did not evaluate to a constant line 15
>
> Message       - failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not
> declared 'constexpr'  line 15

I do understand the warnings for `val1` and `val2`, but then when I do use `constexpr` for `val3`, I get an error. Why does this throw an error when almost the same code, encapsulated in another function (`foo()`) doesn't? From my (limited) understanding, can't `myInt()` also be computed at compile time?

Comment: please include the compilers error message in the quesiton. Error codes are compiler specific and the message usually contains more useful information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because, at the point of use (in the `constexpr int val3 = myInt();` line), the compiler does not have a *definition* of `myInt()`, and so cannot (safely) deduce a *compile-time* constant value.

The solution is to put that *definition* of the `myInt` function *before* its use (where you currently have its *forward declaration*):

```cpp
constexpr int myInt() { return 1; }

int main()
{
    int val1 = myInt();           // C26498 warning (mark variable constexpr)
    const int val2 = myInt();     // C26498 warning (mark variable constexpr)
    constexpr int val3 = myInt(); // No error or warning!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the error, thank you. Does that mean it is standard practice in modern C++ to put the definitions at the beginning of the file? Also, why does it work for `foo()`?

Comment: It works for `foo` (in your code) because, by the time the compiler has reached that, it has *already* encountered the **definition** of `myInt`. You can have both forward-declaration and definition, but you need the latter *before* you try to use it in a `constexpr` statement.

Comment: Oh yeah, from the perspective of `foo()`, `getMyValue()` was already defined. I missed that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The function must be defined before its call. Most of the time this does not happen because a constexpr function is "implicitly" inline and is defined within the '.h' and so is included in top of the code before compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to declare myInt() before using it (above main() function):

```
constexpr int myInt();
constexpr int getMyValue();
void foo();

constexpr int myInt() { return 1; }

int main()
{
    int val1 = myInt(); // C26498 warning (mark variable constexpr)
    const int val2 = myInt();    // C26498 warning (mark variable constexpr)
    constexpr int val3 = myInt();  // C2131 error (expression did not evaluate to a constant)

}

constexpr int getMyValue() { return 1; }

void foo() { constexpr int val0 = getMyValue(); // no C26498 }
```

It worked in my PC (g++ (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0)